# How to pass context to second widget tree for provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am try **pass context to second widget tree** (in function) but I get error:

> Tried to use Provider with a subtype of Listenable/Stream (Model2).
>   This is likely a mistake, as Provider will not automatically update
>   dependents when Model2 is updated. Instead, consider changing Provider
>   for more specific implementation that handles the update mecanism,
>   such as: 
>   - ListenableProvider
>   - ChangeNotifierProvider
>   - ValueListenableProvider 
>   - StreamProvider

```
Future<void> _neverSatisfied({Key key, @required BuildContext context}) async {

final model2 = Provider.of<Model2>(context, listen: false);

  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, 
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return 


    Provider.value(value: model2, child:


AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
              Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Regret'),
            onPressed: () async {
await model2.getData();

              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

First widget in same `StatefulWidget`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Model1, Model2>(
initialBuilder: (_) => Model2(),
  builder: (_, model1, model2) => model2
    ..string = model1.string,
),
  child: Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
```

Second (**I pass context from here**):

```
  @override
  Widget buildStep(BuildContext context) {
  Consumer<Model2>(
    builder: (context, model2, _) =>
...

   _neverSatisfied(context: context); //**pass context**
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Provider.value` you should use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`

Comment: Thanks!         `ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => Model2,` also work I think! I not know difference with `ChangeNotifierProvider.value`

Comment: No, don't use it. It will dispose the notifier when you leave the route, which is undesired.